# Azure table storage multiple calls failing

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I am trying to add/edit items in Azure Table storage. I am able to get each call to work but if I do multiple calls e.g. a retrieve and then a merge the 2nd call will fail. It will also fail if I run 2 retrieve calls. I have tried different calls and each time the 1st works but any further ones fail with this error.

The error message I get is:

```
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have created a small console app just to test the calls:

```
namespace AzureTest
{
    public class Azure
    {
        private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("XXXXXXX");

        public async Task Get(string partition, string key)
        {
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("AzureTable");

            TableOperation getOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TableItem>(partition, key);

            await table.ExecuteAsync(getOperation);
        }
    }

    public class TableItem : TableEntity
    {
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }
        public string Json { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I call this Get method once it is successful but if i try to call again it fails. I have tried creating a new instance of the CloudStorageAccount in each call but that still fails.

I have tried calling the methods different way, just calling the method multiple times and using the Task.WaitAll option.

```
Get(partition, key).Wait();
Get(partition, key).Wait();
```

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Get(partition, key));
tasks.Add(Get(partition, key));
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
```

Comment: please show us the code you call the get method, and also in the TableItem class, you're missing a constructor method.

Comment: @IvanYang i have added in a couple of different ways that i tried to call the Get method

Comment: I used your code and it does not reproduce. which nuget package are you using?

Comment: I am using WindowsAzure.Storage (9.3.3) and have 3 using statements using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table and System.Threading.Tasks. Should also say the test app I created is .net core 2.2 console app

Comment: @IvanYang after your last comment, it made me think so I tested creating a console app using .net framework 4.7 and it worked. I have tried using .net core 2.1 and it also failed. I may just have to create this project using .NET Framework

Comment: I'm using .net framework, not .net core, so it works that time. I will take a try with .net core next day. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: thanks for all the help, been trying so many different things for days but never thought to not use .net core.

Comment: Hi chris, I post an answer for summarize. And could you please help mark it as answer, if you don't know how to mark, please follow this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Comment: I also tested it with .net core 2.2 at my side, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

Test it with .net framework, and everything works well.

It only occurs on the .net core.

So as workaround, use .net framework for the project.